# Maxmind API выдаёт ошибку при попытке получения данных

Tags: python, api

Задача в том, чтобы из IP (который я задаю) вытаскивать его IPScore (fraud_score, если угодно).

Я создала аккаунт в maxmind, получила ключ доступа и в итоге выдает ошибку: `minfraud.errors.PermissionRequiredError: You do not have permission to use this service interface`

```py
from minfraud import Client
client = Client(accountid,'license key')
client.factors({'device': {'ip_address': '152.216.7.110'}})
```

Может, у кого-то был опыт в использование данного сервиса?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, который вызывает данную ошибку?

Comment: в рабочем коде так и написано ``'license key'``?

Comment: нет конечно....

Comment: желательно чтобы просто помогли вытащить Fraud_score